# Updating Lambda to AWS through intellij plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-toolkit

I'm uploading a Spring Application to a Lambda function on AWS through IntelliJ's AWS Toolkit but when uploading the code to the S3 bucket it runs sam build and yields the following error:

```
2019-04-23 19:44:41 Building resource 'Function'
2019-04-23 19:44:41 Running JavaMavenWorkflow:CopySource
2019-04-23 19:44:48 Running JavaMavenWorkflow:MavenBuild
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflow.py", line 248, in run
    action.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\java_maven\actions.py", line 40, in execute
    self.subprocess_maven.build(self.scratch_dir)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflows\java_maven\maven.py", line 32, in build
    LOG.debug("Maven logs: %s", stdout.decode('utf8').strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 31648: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 220, in _build_function_in_process
    mode=self._mode)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\builder.py", line 115, in build
    return workflow.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflow.py", line 65, in wrapper
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\aws_lambda_builders\workflow.py", line 263, in run
    reason=str(ex))
aws_lambda_builders.exceptions.WorkflowUnknownError: JavaMavenWorkflow:MavenBuild - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 31648: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\osutils.py", line 36, in mkdir_temp
    yield temp_dir
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 199, in _build_function
    runtime)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 222, in _build_function_in_process
    raise BuildError(str(ex))
samcli.lib.build.app_builder.BuildError: JavaMavenWorkflow:MavenBuild - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 31648: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli(prog_name="sam")
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 100, in cli
    skip_pull_image, parameter_overrides, mode)  # pragma: no cover
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 141, in do_cli
    artifacts = builder.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 108, in build
    lambda_function.runtime)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 199, in _build_function
    runtime)
  File "contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\osutils.py", line 40, in mkdir_temp
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
  File "shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
  File "shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
  File "shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
  File "shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
  File "shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
  File "shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\MYUSR~1.T-C\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmprnqr_8tf\\.git\\objects\\00\\1d37e180fc93c0908cd70014bc75d1b2ae8bfd'
```

Had to change the function's region and update the IDE and somehow it stopped working.

Java 8
AWS Toolkit v1.2
sam >> SAM CLI 0.15.0
aws >> aws-cli/1.16.144 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.134

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 31648: invalid start byte
```

I have posted a workaround here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261416/sam-build-in-intellij-error-javamavenworkflowmavenbuild-utf-8-codec-cant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70036186/346112)